# Codeception undexpected behaviuor (not running all CEPT tasks with Yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I has a test class with 4 test functions. When I run *codecept run* there is only 1 function is called and no assertions applied.

I use Yii2 advanced template, *frontend* folder is used for REST API (I'll rename it after a while). I tryed to write API tests like it was defined in [the guide](http://codeception.com/docs/10-WebServices), and it works if I has every test in different file, like in the guide. But database is not cleared before each test and it's too uncomfortable to has similar tests in different files, not to mention fixtures.

Config:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            url: 'http://localhost:8000'
            part: [json]
        - Yii2:
            part: [orm, fixtures]
            entryScript: index-test.php
```

Code:

```
use Codeception\Util\HttpCode;

class RegisterCept
{
    public function successRegister(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo("register successfully");
        $params = [
            'username' => 'ApiTester',
            'password' => '12345678',
            'email' => 'ApiTester@ApiTester.yii'
        ];
        $I->sendPOST('/users/register', $params);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::CREATED);
        $I->canSeeResponseIsJson();
        $I->seeResponseContains('');
    }

    public function getMethod(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('be sure I can\'t register by GET method');
        $params = [
            'username' => 'ApiTester',
            'password' => '12345678',
            'email' => 'ApiTester@ApiTester.yii'
        ];
        $I->sendGET('/users/register', $params);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::NOT_FOUND);
    }

    public function emptyRequest(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('be sure I can\'t register a new user without a username, password or e-mail');
        $I->sendPOST('/users/register');
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::BAD_REQUEST);
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();
        $I->seeResponseContainsJson(
            [
                'errors' => [
                    'username' => ['Username cannot be blank.'],
                    'email' => ['Email cannot be blank.'],
                    'password' => ['Password cannot be blank.'],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    public function disallowRepeatedRegister(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo("Not to register second time");

        $params = [
            'username' => 'ApiTester',
            'password' => '12345678',
            'email' => 'ApiTester@ApiTester.yii'
        ];
        $I->sendPOST('/users/register', $params);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::CREATED);
        $I->canSeeResponseIsJson();
        $I->seeResponseContains('');

        $I->sendPOST('/users/register', $params);
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::BAD_REQUEST);
        $I->canSeeResponseIsJson();
        $I->canSeeResponseContainsJson(
            [
                'errors' => [
                    'username' => 'This username has already been taken',
                    'email' => 'This email address has already been taken',
                ],
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

Trying to run tests:

[image: Running tests]

Comment: do select the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that your test runs at all.
Cept format is intended to a plain file with no functions or classes: http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Writing-a-Sample-Scenario

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->sendPOST('/users/register', $params);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::CREATED);
$I->canSeeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContains('');
```

In order to have multiple test methods in one file, you have to use Cest format: http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Cept-Cest-and-Test-Formats

Which looks like your example, but you have to use Cest suffix instead of Cept in file name and class name.

Comment: Great thanks!! Yesterday I've tried to do the same, but smthng went wrong. Now everything is working!